# WP All Import str_replace (WooCommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In WP All Import I am trying to use the `str_replace` function for editing several Attributes (color).

I use this tutorial http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/execute-php/

In Function Editor I put function:

```
<?php
function replace($color){
str_replace("Fish Blanket", "Shrimp Blanket", $color);
str_replace( "Digi Plaid", "Sgt Bilko Brown", $color);
return $color;
}
?>
```

Then in Color values field I insert `[replace({color[1]})]` and nothing happens.

Also I tried to insert several `str_replace` into Color Values using `|` :

```
[str_replace("Digi Plaid", "Sgt Bilko Brown", {color[1]})] | [str_replace("Fish Blanket", "Shrimp Blanket", {color[1]})] |  [str_replace("Rasta", "Pasta", {color[1]})]
```

Could you please advise what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
[color_change({color[1]})]
```

in function editor:

```
function color_change($color){
$color = str_replace("Fish Blanket", "Shrimp Blanket",$color);
$color = str_replace("Digi Plaid", "Sgt Bilko Brown",$color);
return $color;}
```